# Keyboard disconnects then connects to a different machine

Tags: keyboard, imac, bluetooth

We had a 2013 iMac, then added a 27" 2020 iMac on the desk next to it and have had no issues whatsoever with the keyboard/mouse connections via Bluetooth.

About 2 months ago, we added a 3rd (Apple Silicone) iMac to the collection, and have had 3 or 4 instances of the keyboard from the 2020 machine disconnecting and connecting to the 2023 iMac.

It takes turning the offending keyboard off, deleting the connection from the newest iMac, turning the keyboard back on and having it connect to the newest machine and repeating the cycle several times before we can finally get it to connect to the correct machine.

- Is this a known issue?
- Are there any recommendations for preventing this from happening again in the future?

  - No, moving the machines out of BT range isn't an option for us.

We have *not* had similar issues with any of the mice, and it's only been the one keyboard that reconnects to the wrong machine, and it only ever incorrectly connects to the newest Mac in the fleet.

Comment: Have you, by chance, paired the keyboard to both the 2020 and 2023 iMacs (not simultaneously, of course)?  Are you using the same AppleID on both machines by chance? I can't see how a BT keyboard would jump from one computer to the next *without* pairing it first.  That would make running a Mac lab in a school setting a nightmare.

Comment: We never _intentionally_ paired the errant keyboard to the wrong Mac. IIRC, the first time this happened, the other person lost the ability to type and the Mac popped up the "keyboard disconnected" notification. At that point, I may have opened the BT settings on the "wrong" machine and the keyboard paired to whatever was available. I do believe we _are_ using the same Apple ID on both machines (obviously not in front of them right now). Having seen pics of Mac labs, I figured this wasn't a frequent occurrence, but it's happened enough times now that it's _really_ annoying.

Comment: I would start by going into the settings of both machines, "forgetting" the keyboards, then pairing them again.  Since the keyboards aren't multi-host capable, they shouldn't bounce from one machine to the next.   I can only imagine how annoying this is...